# Google Sheets Script to Rearrange Rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-sheets-formula

Trying to create a Google Sheet that allows selection of row priority with dropdown selection option.

Here's a basic algorithm that I am trying to build out:

1 User changes the priority of the row using the dropdown (Note: That part works fine)

2 The edited row will move up to the position based on the new priority (Note: That part works fine)

3 All other rows will change their numbers based on the edited cell (i.e. Say, the edited cell was originally 13 and changed to 4. I want the old 4 to become 5 and everything from 5 to 12 to increase 1)

The issue I'm having is when the cell is changed to number 4, it goes under the old number 4 - hence a for loop doesn't work.

Anyone done anything similar or have suggestions?

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = activeSheet.getActiveCell();


  var columnToSortBy = 1;
  var tableRange = "A2:M22";

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){
   var priority =  editedCell.getValue();
   var range = activeSheet.getRange(tableRange);
   var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT", "HH:mm:ss");
   var nextCell = editedCell.offset(0, 13);
    nextCell.setValue(time);


   range.sort({ column: columnToSortBy, ascending: true});

  } 
}

function rearrangeRows() {
  var i;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 1;
  var endRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var getRange = ss.getDataRange();
  var getRow = getRange.getRow();

  var testPriority = 3;

  var cell = ss.getRange("A4");
  var cellValue = cell.getValue();
  if (cellValue > number) {
   Logger.log(cellValue);  
  }
  Logger.log(number);

 // for(i; i > )
}
```

Comment: Rather than just sorting the range when the priority changes, consider inserting a row at the desired position, moving/copying the edited row to that row, deleting the old row (if necessary, maybe it is already gone due to the move), and then incrementing the values of all row numbers between the target row position (derivable from `event.value`) and the old row position (derivable from `event.oldValue`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could put code like what I've written below in the onEdit function, before you sort the spreadsheet. This should increase the value of all the cells with a priority higher than the priority you just set, ignoring the cell you just changed. You may have to adapt it slightly to work also when you decrease the priority of a row, as you'll want to decrease the priority of all the rows in between the row's original priority and its new priority.

```
var endRow = activeSheet.getLastRow();
for (var i = 1; i <= endRow; i ++) {
    var currentCell = activeSheet.getRange("A" + i);
    if (currentCell.getValue() > priority && i != editedCell.getRow()) {
         currentCell.setValue(currentCell.getValue() + 1)
    }
}
```